# Arraylist in Visual Studio .net 2005

Tags: c#-2.0

How can i store three different objects in a single array list for populating tree view?

Answer (score 0):

Well, generally this sounds like a bad idea.  Please describe why you want to do this.

If possible, a clean way to do this is to create a base class for all three objects that your tree view would bind to.  (There may be other interesting solutions, like creating a Facade/Adapter object over the three.)